# Server-side JavaScript - how lookup rows in data extension in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I just started using SSJS and the syntax is a bit new.

I need to check if a subsriber exists in a data extension, based on email address.

```
if (IsEmailAddress(submitterEmail)){
var requestsDE = DataExtension.Init('dataextensionname');
var exists = requestsDE.Rows.Lookup(["email"], [submitterEmail]);
var rows = rowCount(exists);
if rows < 1 {
alert('less than one row')
}
else do stuff
```

So I want to check if the email address 'submitterEmail' at all exists in the data extension (column 'email'), and then I want to count if there are any rows. If there is I eventlually want to update the row, else I want to add a row.

Anyone who please can give me a hint or a code snippet on how to do this?
(my code doesn't work and I think there is something wrong in the countRow or Lookup area)

Comment: The alert() is a client-side function.   It won't work in server-side JavaScript.  You should use the [Write()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/utilities_server_side_javascript_functions/#section_45) function.

Comment: Hi, yeah my bad. I put it there as just a sample.
Should have written 
if rows < 1 {
do stuff
} else { do stuff}

The tricky part for me is just to know if 
var exists and var rows are ok defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **rowCount()** is not a SSJS function in SFMC.

Here's a store lookup example.  It should give you a good place to start:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

try {

    var postalCode = Attribute.GetValue("Zip");
    var storePostalCodeDe = DataExtension.Init("StorePostalCodes");
    var storePostalCode = storePostalCodeDe.Rows.Lookup(["PostalCode"],[postalCode]);
    Variable.SetValue("foundStore", storePostalCode.length > 0);

    if (storePostalCode.length > 0) {
            var storeDe = DataExtension.Init("Stores");
            var stores = storeDe.Rows.Lookup(["StoreID"],[storePostalCode[0].StoreID]);
            var store = stores[0];
            var storeAddress = store.Storename + " " + store.Address1 + " " +"<br>" + store.City + ", " + store.Province + " " + store.PostalCode + ", " + store.Phone
            Variable.SetValue("storeAddress", storeAddress)
    }

} catch (e) {
  Write("<br>Exception: " + e);
}

</script>
<br>foundStore: %%=v(@foundStore)=%%
<br>storeAddress: %%=v(@storeAddress)=%%
```

**Reference**

[**Core Library Server-Side JavaScript Functions**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/)

Comment: I tried this but can still not get it to work. Any additional hints?
`
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var submitterEmail = Request.GetFormField('EmailAddress');
var requestsDE = DataExtension.Init('myDataExtension');
var subscriberSearch = requestsDE.Rows.Lookup(["email"],[submitterEmail]);
if (subscriberSearch.length < 1) {
requestsDE.Rows.Add({ //pull into DE
email: Request.GetFormField('EmailAddress')
});
}else { //update
requestsDE.Rows.Update({ //pull into DE
email: Request.GetFormField('EmailAddress')
}); 
}//end if
`

Comment: I'd add a try/catch block to trap the error.  I updated my example above.

Comment: Your lookup code was of great help, and I also needed to do some readup on how the update function worked. So you helped me in the right direction. 

Thank you so much Marketing Cloud Guru - I've been in and out of your blogg several times. You are doing such a great work both on the blogg and here. Keep it up! OK now you can edit this post and remove these lines... I just had to say it :-)